# Multisite blog converting categories to subdomains

Tags: categories, multisite, redirect

Having `http://site.com/category/xyz` = `http://xyz.site.com/`

I would like to move the content from each category to its equivalent subdomain blog, so that when I will access `http://site.com/new-post/`, where the post belongs to category `XYZ`, `site.com` will do a `301` redirect to `http://xyz.site.com/new-post/`

So, is there any other way besides then the hardcore extracting data from database and move it to its new place?

Comment: I think its possible but needs serious custom code to accomplish this.
I suggest to check http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/ plugin code for a start.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Move to Subsite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/move-to-subsite) plugin? It sounds perfect for what you want to achieve

Comment: Are you sure [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) isn't what you are looking for? You can easily achieve that in a multisite.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

1. download and install this plugin: [WP-Universe](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-universe/)

> WP-Universe creates a blog universe based on categories of a WordPress blog.
>
> go to Manage Category
>
> edit the category description with the category subdomain (check the [install guide](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-universe/installation/))
>   `http://cat-slug.example.com/`
>
> now make your subdomains
>
> et voilà

Comment: I'm sorry for my English. 'm stupid Italian

Comment: not stupid, maybe crazy ;) Stupid is very hard in the english words.

Comment: Nice little 4 years old gem! In my localhost multisite it is not working, maybe with a MS sub-domain set-up it'll need some `.htaccess` rules... No problem with *Engrish*, we can try to correct it, but your French is not good either ;)

Comment: Couldn't make it work in single site neither, but nice concept behind, maybe workable with more brain-power.

Comment: -1 for the recommendation of using such an old plug-in. In my experience, using old plug-ins can lead to compatibility issues as well open up security holes. I recently had the "joy" of cleaning up a fairly new site full of old plug-ins (installed by the designer - who clearly was not a developer) that got hacked through vulnerabilities in two of them.